# Using _uid and Iteration

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to iterate and check some boxes based on an array of data. The way I was trying to do it (using `_uid`) did not seem to work.

JS:

```
//The second checkbox will be checked by default
var build = [true, true, false]

let enhancements = [
  {
    name: "Action One"
  },
  {
    name: "Action Two"
  },
  {
    name: "Action Three"
  }
]

Vue.component('cleanse-checkbox', {
  props: ['enhancement'],

  data() {
    return {
      isSelected: 'action-point-on',
      notSelected: 'action-point-off',
      build: build[this._uid-1]
    };
  },

  template: `
    <div class="mb-2">
      <p>{{ build }}</p>
      <button :class="[isActive ? isSelected : notSelected, notSelected]" 
        v-on:click="toggleEnhancement">{{ enhancement.name }}</button>
    </div>
  `,

  computed: {
    isActive: function () {
      return this.build;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleEnhancement: function() {
      this.build = this.build == 0;
      this.$emit('toggle-enhancement', [this._uid-1, this.build])
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
    build: build,
    enhancements: enhancements
  },

  methods: {
    updateEnhancement: function (value) {
      this.build[value[0]] = value[1]
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <p>${ build }</p>
    <cleanse-checkbox v-for="enhancement in enhancements"
                      :enhancement="enhancement"
                      v-on:toggle-enhancement="updateEnhancement">    </cleanse-checkbox>
</div>
```

Is there a proper 'vue' way to accomplish something like this? Or am I on the right track using improper syntax? Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wb37t84j/

Comment: What is `_uid`?

Comment: @Saurabh `_uid` is a Vue internal id on vNodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tumbled into "[gotcha](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)" in Vue. Vue cannot detect the change you are making on this line.

```
this.build[value[0]] = value[1]
```

Also, I would avoid using `_uid`. Here is a version of your code that works.

```
let build = [true, true, false]

let enhancements = [
  {
    name: "Action One"
  },
  {
    name: "Action Two"
  },
  {
    name: "Action Three"
  }
]

Vue.component('cleanse-checkbox', {
  props: ['enhancement', 'build'],

  data() {
    return {
      isSelected: 'action-point-on',
      notSelected: 'action-point-off',
      internalBuild: this.build
    };
  },

  template: `
    <div class="mb-2">
      <p>{{ build }}</p>
      <button :class="[isActive ? isSelected : notSelected, notSelected]" 
        v-on:click="toggleEnhancement">{{ enhancement.name }}</button>
    </div>
  `,

  computed: {
    isActive: function () {
      return this.internalBuild;
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleEnhancement: function() {
      this.internalBuild = !this.internalBuild
      this.$emit('toggle-enhancement', this.enhancement, this.internalBuild)
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
    build: build,
    enhancements: enhancements
  },

  methods: {
    updateEnhancement: function (enhancement, build) {
      Vue.set(this.build, this.enhancements.indexOf(enhancement), build)
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the modified template

```
<div id="app">
    <p>${ build }</p>
    <cleanse-checkbox v-for="(enhancement, index) in enhancements"
                      :enhancement="enhancement"
                      :build="build[index]"
                      v-on:toggle-enhancement="updateEnhancement">    
     </cleanse-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to still be firing an error off: `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "build" 
(found in component <cleanse-checkbox>)`

Comment: @PaulELI can you show me that on a fiddle? I do not see that error.

Comment: @PaulELI I added the template I am using so we are on the same page. Forgot I modified it.

Comment: Nod, it works, but I am still seeing an error in the console log:      In the toggleEnhancement method `this.build = !this.build` is bringing up that error.

Comment: @PaulELI Derp. Sorry, updated code should work. I'm not sure why my codepen didn't show the warning because that's a common mistake.

Comment: Really appreciate the time and help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137480/discussion-between-pauleli-and-bert-evans).